# Why has my project started showing reference to DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, dotnetzip, ionic-zip

I am moving to another machine and have installed latest version of VS 2022.
I have references to Ionic.Zlib in my project but now it started showing reference to DotNetZip as well.
Due to this it throws a compile time error - The type 'GZipStream' exists in both 'DotNetZip' Version...
and 'Ionic.Zlib' ...

I looked to remove the reference to DotNetZip from References but it doesn't have any option.

Comment: It is very strange that such a reference has suddenly appeared without having been previously included. How did you tried to remove the reference? Did you used NuGet (`PM> NuGet\Uninstall-Package DotNetZip -Version x.xx.x`) or .NET CLI (`> dotnet remove package DotNetZip --version x.xx.x`) commands?

Comment: well...found a solution. The problem was, another branch that I used, had DotNetZip as a Nuget package but the one I work on doesn't. I was cleaning and building the project but yet was getting the error. Deleting the obj folders from the projects causing issue worked for me!!!